# Автоматизация копирования (удаления) подмножества строк

Tags: windows, notepad++, поиск-программ

Есть файл, открытый в `Notepad++`. Требуется скопировать строки с 3697 по 3976 в другой файл. Существует ли программа, осуществляющая такое копирование?

Comment: *Существует ли программа, осуществляющая такое копирование?* Что, из программы рулить NPP? да вряд ли... а если просто скопировать заданные строки из одного текстового файла в другой - так с этим даже обычный CMD-процессинг справится.

Comment: например: `$ sed -n '3697,3976p' первый.файл > второй.файл`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin мне нужно копирование в windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/127567/4827341

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а как установить sed на windows?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin в ссылке приведенной вами сказано, что sed предназначен для unix (а не для windows), а мне нужна программа для windows

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin вы где?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, а ответ написать?

Answer (score 0):

Раз уж есть открытый NPP с файлом, то можно в нём и сделать:

1. Даблклик по позиции в файле

   [image: скриншот окна NPP]
2. Перейти к строке 3697

   [image: скриншот окна перехода]
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>
4. <kbd>Delete</kbd>
5. Перейти к строке 3977 (на 1 больше последней нужной)
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>
7. <kbd>Delete</kbd>
8. Файл -> Сохранить как